# How Do I Pull the Time Until Sleep of the Active Power Plan?

Tags: windows, powershell, sleep, power-management

I'm looking for either a PowerShell script or command that allows me to get the active power plan's time until sleep.

In the below example, I know from the previous screen that "Balanced" is the Active Power plan. Selecting that, gets to this screen where I can see this info.

[image: Sleep settings]

I've currently tried places in both WMI and the registry, but everything is set to GUIDs and you have to pull the Active Powerplan first. I have also tried `powercfg` and it various commands.

Do I have to query the active powerplan with powercfg, parse that response, so I only get the GUID, and then query using that result in the registry or WMI?

Looking for some guidance or even some code.

Comment: That route seems fine. `powercfg` has a flag `/GETACTIVESCHEME` which will help, then you need to isolate the GUID. You can use this to reduce the output of `powercfg /QUERY`. You can also find the active plan with `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_powerplan -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Filter "isActive='true'"`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to retrieve the power plan setting, not the actual current time remaining until sleep?  Also, you want to retrieve and store the value in a form you can use programmatically, not just display the setting?

Comment: @fixer1234 Correct on both accounts